# fullcallendar v4 info.event.start shows different time than displayed in calendar

Tags: javascript, timezone, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Calendar (fullcalendar v4) shows the event with proper time as read from the database and adjusted to required timezone.

I have event displayed between 12.00 and 14.00.

Part of calendar initialization:

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'interaction' ],
    allDaySlot: false,
    selectable: true,
    timeZone: '<?php echo $calendar_timezone ?>',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    nowIndicator: true,
    slotDuration: '<?php echo $calendar_full_hours_only ?>',
    businessHours: {
        startTime: '08:00',
        endTime:   '19:00',
        daysOfWek:[1,2,3,4,5]
    },
}
```

JSON feed is good. event shows properly in calendar grid:

```
[
{
"id": 53,
"title": "Test Event 12.00 - 14.00",
"start": "2019-11-19 12:00",
"end": "2019-11-19 14:00",
"allDay": 0,
"editable": 1
}
]
```

When it is clicked it shows different time.

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    console.log('Id: ' + info.event.id);
    console.log('Start: ' + info.event.start);
    console.log('End: ' + info.event.end);
    console.log('Calendar timezone: ' + '<?php echo $calendar_timezone ?>');
    console.log('Browser timezone: ' + Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone);
}
```

Output in the console is:

```
Id: 53
Start: Fri Nov 19 2019 13:00:00 GMT+0100 (czas środkowoeuropejski standardowy)
End: Fri Nov 19 2019 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (czas środkowoeuropejski standardowy)
Calendar timezone: Europe/Warsaw
Browser timezone: Europe/Warsaw
```

Which is one hour later than shown in the calendar.

What is more, If I change timezone of the calendar to another timezone it corrects time of the event shown in the calendar, but again if I click them it shows time one hour later. Can't figure out what is happening.

I have just discovered that problem does not occur if I click empty slot. Then time is correct. It happens only when I click existing event.

Comment: Can you please show the original JSON event data you provided to fullCalendar in order to display this event? And...what is the default timezone in your browser when you run this? And...are you using any of fullCalendar's timezone settings? Please provide us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can fully understand and reproduce all the factors which are influencing the behaviour you're asking about. Thanks.

Comment: In a first place, thank you for trying to help. I read the data from mysql and the strangest thing is that they are displayed with correct time. Then I click them so I don't do anything with them with my code and they display wrong time. At the same time when I click empty slot in calendar it displays correct time. Any ideas what to check or test?

Comment: Can it be related to 1h slotDuration?

Comment: No, slotDuration is completely irrelevant

Comment: Did you read and understand the implications of setting a timezone as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeZone? It changes the way you need to provide event data to fullCalendar, and the way you need to read it, and it usually helps you if you use a timezone plugin, which you haven't mentioned. **But**...you seem to be setting the timezone to be the same one that your browser is already set to. So unless you are planning to ever view this page from a different timezone, you don't really need it. It just makes things more complicated.

Comment: Hi, I think it is related to DST (Daylight Saving Time) change. When I added test event in April, after clicking it, I got start and end moved by two hours forward. So I don't know the answer yet, but I know what to look for. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: ADyson, thank you for the clues. Now it works fine no matter which TZ server is installed in or which TZ clients connect from. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in interaction between fullcalendar and Bootstrap 4 Datetimepicker, which treated all dates read from fullcalendar event as UTC time.
Adding Moments Timezone to both fullcalendar and Datetimepicker solved the issue.

Comment: Can you show more details on how you solved this as I have the same problem using Fullcalendar with BS4. Thx

Comment: I am converting the date: `$dateTime_for_picker = new DateTime ($source_date_object_UTC->format(DATETIMEFORMAT_PHP), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
return $dateTime_for_picker->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z');` before it is passed to datetimepicker